# Add click button to return to the change_form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I am extending the Django admin. I have a click button on the change_form that takes me to another customized page. I want to add a button on the customized page to take me back to the change_form (keeping track of the instance I am working on by the object_id). What do I put in the href of the click button to go back to the change form? My guess was this:

```
<a class="changeform" href="{% url 'admin:change_form' object_id %}">{% trans "Click HERE to return." %}</a>
```

but that does not work. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your view name (instead of `admin:change_form`) should be along the lines of `admin:myapp_mymodel_change`